# Looping over InputStream truncating data

Tags: java, loops, input, io

So this is a very simple problem with a simple solution that I'm just not seeing:

I'm trying to get a list of data through an InputStream, looping until I reach the end of the stream. On each iteration, I print the next line of text being passed through the InputStream. I have it working but for one small problem: I'm truncating the first character of each line.

Here's the code:

```
while (dataInputStream.read() >= 0) {
    System.out.printf("%s\n", dataInputReader.readLine());
}
```

And the output:

```
classpath
project
est.txt
```

Now, I know what's going on here: the `read()` call in my `while` loop is taking the first char on each line, so when the line gets passed into the loop, that char is missing. The problem is, I can't figure out how to set up a loop to prevent that.

I think I just need a new set of eyes on this.

Comment: There is an `available()` method on this class, have you tried it?

Comment: Is your variable `dataInputStream` or `dataInputReader`? And what's its type? More clarity in the question, please.

Comment: @JonSkeet my guess is that there is a reader wrapped over the input stream (and that the stream is tested for data... Strange way to operate but ohwell)

Comment: Sorry, dataInputStream is the stream coming from the socket and dataInputReader is the BufferedReader coming from dataInputStream. I'm new to this sort of thing, so I welcome C&C.

Comment: OK, what do you want to do with your data ultimately? Only read it line by line?

Comment: @fge So I'm making a file transfer utility. This part is to simply list the files available on the server, so the server sends a list of the contents of a directory and this code (on the client) prints that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readLine` for `DataInputStream` is deprecated. You may try wrapping it with a `BufferedReader`:

```
try
{
    String line;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( dataInputStream ) );
    while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
    { 
        System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
    }  
} 
catch( IOException e )
{
    System.err.println( "Error: " + e );
}
```

Also, I`m not sure, that it is a good idea to use available() due to this specification:

```
* <p>Note that this method provides such a weak guarantee that it is not very useful in
* practice.
```

Comment: This fixes the truncating issue, but it doesn't break out of the while loop. This may be an issue with the string being passed into it, though.

Comment: Then you can make without a buffered wrapper and use simple read() until it will give you '-1'.

Comment: So you're saying while(dataInputStream.read() != -1) { ... }? As far as I can tell, that'd put the truncation issue back in.

Comment: I mean this: byte b; while( (b = dataInputStream.read()) != -1) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Use one `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`, here is one example:

```
InputStream in=...;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
while (br.ready()) {
    String line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataInputStream.read()` reads the first character of the InputStream, the same as `dataInputReader.readLine()` reads the complete next line. Every read character or line is then gone. you can use the `dataInputStream.available()` to check if the InputStream has data available. 
That should print the correct output:

```
while (dataInputStream.available()) {
  System.out.printf("%s", dataInputReader.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line;
while ((line = dataInputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
 }
```